# How to give JPA create table privileges on oracle

Tags: spring, oracle, jpa, oracle19c

I'm trying to change my database MySQL to oracle. But when I try to change oracle table not create and below mention error is appear. however all the required sequence will create on oracle but not create table.

Error :

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:628)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:562)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:1145)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:726)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:291)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:492)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:108)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:997)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeSQLStatement(OracleStatement.java:1507)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1287)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeInternal(OracleStatement.java:2137)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.execute(OracleStatement.java:2092)
        at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.execute(OracleStatementWrapper.java:328)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95)
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java)
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54)
        ... 38 common frames omitted
    Caused by: oracle.jdbc.OracleDatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer11.processError(T4CTTIoer11.java:632)
        ... 53 common frames omitted
    Hibernate: drop temp_his cascade constraints
```

Comment: I don't know tools you use. However, "ORA-00942: table or view does not exist" is usually related to SELECT statement that is trying to fetch data from table (or view) that doesn't exist (as error says). So: is there anything like that in code you use? To me, it doesn't look like *insufficient privileges* issue; error would've been different

Comment: The error is `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`. Whatever you are trying to do you are trying to do it against a table that does not exist. Either fix the errors in your code (which you have not shared) so that the table name is correct or ensure you are connecting to the correct database and/or user and that the table name does not require quoted identifiers and is visible to the user you are connecting with.

Comment: yes this is empty schema and JPA will create the all the relevant table .problem is table not creating and only create the seq